# How do I get rid of the coefficient in this congruence?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$ax^2 = b \bmod m$$

I am trying to get rid of the $a$ so I can apply Tonelli-Shanks to the result to solve for $x$. But since $a$ and $m$ are not always coprime, I cannot always multiply both sides by the inverse of $a$ mod $m$.

Assume that $\gcd(a,b,m) = 1$, however.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ and $m$ have a common factor, $n$ (say), that is **not** a factor of $b$ then there is no $x$ that satisfies the equation.

For any $x$, $ax^2- b$ does NOT have a factor of $n$ while $m$ does so cannot be congruent to $0$ modulo $m$.

Comment: Also interested in this. What does your last sentence mean?

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts (seven out of 8 answers you posted yesterday!) need heavy editing.